# Count the number of unique character elements in one column based on several different (sub-)groupings (columns)

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

Here is a sample dataset.

```
test_data <- structure(list(ID = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("P39190", 
"U93491", "X28348", "Z93930"), class = "factor"), Sex = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("F", "M"), class = "factor"), Group = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("C83Z", "CAP_1", "P000"), class = "factor"), 
    Category = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("A", 
    "B", "C"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("ID", "Sex", "Group", 
"Category"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -36L))

head(test_data, n = 10)
```

> ```
>        ID Sex Group Category
> 1  Z93930   M CAP_1        A
> 2  Z93930   M CAP_1        A
> 3  Z93930   M  C83Z        A
> 4  Z93930   M  C83Z        A
> 5  Z93930   M  C83Z        A
> 6  Z93930   M  C83Z        A
> 7  X28348   F  C83Z        B
> 8  X28348   F  C83Z        B
> 9  X28348   F CAP_1        B
> 10 X28348   F CAP_1        B
> ```

I want to count the number of unique elements  in three levels:

1. Count of unique elements per "Category"
2. Count of unique elements in each "Category" grouped by "Group"
3. Count of unique elements in each "Group" grouped by "Sex"

I can of course use base R and a bit of dplyr to achieve this:

```
library(dplyr)
for(i in 1:length(unique(test_data$Category))){

    temp <- test_data %>% dplyr::filter(Category == unique(test_data$Category)[i])
    message(paste0(unique(test_data$Category)[i]), ": ", length(unique(temp$ID)))

    for(k in 1:length(unique(temp$Group))){
        temp_grp <- temp %>% dplyr::filter(Group == unique(temp$Group)[k])
        message(paste0("\n ├──", unique(temp$Group)[k], 
                       ": ", length(unique(temp_grp$ID))))
        message(paste0("\n\t"), "F: ", length(unique(temp_grp[which(temp_grp$Sex == "F"),])$ID))
        message(paste0("\n\t"), "M: ", length(unique(temp_grp[which(temp_grp$Sex == "M"),])$ID))
    }
}
```

But this is too dirty and unclever.

Is there a function in R that can achieve this in a cleaner and more efficient manner and preferably produce the output in the form of a dataframe?

I was under the impression that `dplyr::group_by` was made for such tasks. But I cannot quite figure out how it works for sub-groupings.

The code below:

```
test_data %>% dplyr::group_by(Category) %>% summarise(n = n_distinct(ID))
```

achieves the first task (point 1. above). But I cannot achieve points 2 and 3 in the same way.

---

**SOLUTION:**

`test_data %>% dplyr::group_by(Category, Group, Sex) %>% summarise(n = n_distinct(ID))`

Comment: I think you just need to group by Category and Group (for 2.) and Group and Sex (for 3.)

Comment: True. I think that `test_data %>% dplyr::group_by(Category, Group, Sex) %>% summarise(n = n_distinct(ID))` is actually doing the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you were not very far from it at all. The idea is just to group by two columns at a time this way: `group_by(col1, col2)`.

For point 2:

```
test_data %>% dplyr::group_by(Category, Group) %>% summarise(n = n_distinct(ID))

Source: local data frame [9 x 3]
Groups: Category [?]
Category  Group     n 
<fctr> <fctr> <int>
1        A   C83Z     1
2        A  CAP_1     1
3        A   P000     2
4        B   C83Z     1
5        B  CAP_1     1
6        B   P000     1
7        C   C83Z     1
8        C  CAP_1     1
9        C   P000     2
```

And for point 3:

```
test_data %>% dplyr::group_by(Group, Sex) %>% summarise(n = n_distinct(ID))
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can use `dplyr::count` for all three cases

```
test_data %>% dplyr::count(Category)
test_data %>% dplyr::count(Group, Category)
test_data %>% dplyr::count(Sex, Group)
```

Comment: Very useful function. If I understand correctly, `dplyr::count(Category, Group)` is basically the shorter version of `dplyr::group_by(Category, Group) %>% summarise(n = n())`. Is there, then, an equivalent for `n_distinct(ID)`? Something like dplyr::count_distinct or count_unique?

Comment: Yes to your first question. You could follow up with `%>% nrow(.)`